# What is the IAR equiavlent of the gcc linker NOLOAD directive?

Tags: gcc, linker, iar

The gcc linker has a directive called NOLOAD that allows a section to be linked but not loaded in the final output.  This directive is placed in the linker scatter file (see the example below).   Is there an equivalent linker directive for IAR Workbench?  I'm currently using IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM V7.20.2.

```
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00010000
    ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x00008000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .my_section (NOLOAD):
    {
        *my_funcs.o(.text*)
    } > rom
```